# Image validation in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

I have created a simple function in `App\Traits\Validate`.
This function simply validates image as seen.

```
public function validate_image($request)
{
    $check = true;
    $validate = $this->validate($request, [
        'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
    ]);
    dd($validate);
    if($validate->fails())
    {
        $check = false;
    }

    return $check;
}
```

Now when I access this function in Controller through

```
$check_image = $this->validate_image($request);
```

I am passing the whole `request` variable. But still in `validate_image` function I am getting `null`. What is that I am missing? I have other functions in `Validate` trait and those are working fine, but this function returning null value. Please help

And yess `image` is the name of the `file` field in form

Comment: Is `dd($validate)` in your function as well ?

Comment: And why are you using extra function for validation of just one image field ?

Comment: @SagarGautam Yesss! I am trying to check if it is returning anything or not.

Comment: There are many images that I have to upload, if I write validation code for all of them, it would make the functions a bit messy.

Comment: While calling your custom validation function, just remove `dd($validate)`.  And you have multiple field from where images are uploaded. Am I right ?

Comment: if I remove `dd($validate)`, since it has null value, the line ` if($validate->fails())` throws error checking on null value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why but try this...

first add

```
use Validator;
```

Now that you are sending `$request` I believe you it in array before passing to `Validator`

This

```
$data[] = $request->files;
    $validate = Validator::make($data, [
        'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
    ]);
```

Now `dd()` this. Hope it works.

Comment: It did work. Don't know what is the problem with `validate` well nvm, it works...

Answer (score 1):

first of all make sure that your form can send files.

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">


{!! Form::open([
     'route' => '',
    'method' => 'POST',
    'files' => true
]) !!}
```

also create custom request. Do you really need validation in controller?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CustomRequest extends FormRequest
{

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work! I have create validate function in trait file. Do you know traits?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that from your form you are able to handle images.
Ensure that in your opening clause you have added:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```